# Using Qt with OpenNI2 and OpenGL to play stream

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, openni

I am using OpenNI2 with PrimeSense to get the 3D model. UI is written with Qt. I am trying to show the 3D point cloud (constructed from depth stream) stream. In the sample, it uses glut so that glutMainLoop() enters the infinity loop that the stream can be shown continuously. How to do that with Qt?

Comment: You may use the PCL library to [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/qt_visualizer.php#qt-visualizer) is a tutorial that hope it helps you, this one is for a static cloud, but you may just change the input cloud every loop with the one coming from openni2.

Comment: Thank you api55. I have found a method to play the video stream. It uses Qt timer and set a time interval to trigger some slot to refresh. The slot is used to re-paint the scene got from the sensor.